# Unable to login to Django admin website after setting SESSION_COOKIE_NAME="__Host-Session"

Tags: python, django, authentication, session-cookies, django-sessions

I have a Django application running locally. I wanted to change the [SESSION_COOKIE_NAME](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#session-cookie-name) to something with the prefix `__Host`, so cookies are only sent to the host that initially set the cookie.

However, I am unable to login into the admin page or the application after I do that. Setting `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` to any other name works well, just not with prefix `__Host`.

Any idea what might be causing this? Could the fact that I am running it locally(so HTTP instead of HTTPS) have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened to your Django project. Actually, I use Django **4.2.1**, then I changed the default session id `sessionid` to `__Host` with [SESSION_COOKIE_NAME](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#session-cookie-name) in `settings.py` as shown below, then I could log in Django Admin normally:

```
# "settings.py"

SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = '__Host'
```